# How to display block and none all background images stacked with absolute with JS?

Tags: javascript

I am creating an array with 16 divs dynamically on load. I have stacked all the divs with position absolute with CSS. Now, I would like to display block and display none with a set time interval and repeat this over and over again if beginning and end is reached a loop.

This is my code:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
    images.forEach((image, index) => {
        let imageDiv = document.createElement('div');
        imageDiv.className = `bg-image bg-image-bg${image}`;
        hero.appendChild(imageDiv);
        console.log(index);
        console.log(imageDiv);
    });
}
```

it generates 16 divs with a class bg-image. Now, I would like to display block and display none from 1 to 16 loop it over and over again.

This is what I would like to achieve: https://codepen.io/thomasvaeth/pen/JrjyjW (But without the hover effect).

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At img div creation you push them in an array, then you call the same function every 500ms (in my eg) thah hides all the img and display incrementally the right one :

```
let imgArr = [];
if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
    images.forEach((image, index) => {
        let imageDiv = document.createElement('div');
        imageDiv.className = `bg-image bg-image-bg${image}`;
        hero.appendChild(imageDiv);
        console.log(index);
        console.log(imageDiv);
        imgArr.push(imageDiv);
    });
}

let counter = 0;

function roll() {
    imgArr.map( img => img.style.display = 'none' );
    imgArr[counter].style.display = 'block';
    counter++;
    if(counter == imgArr.length - 1) counter = 0;
    setTimeout(()=>roll(), 500);
}

setTimeout(() => roll(), 0);
```

or :

```
let counter = 0;

function roll() {
    imgArr.map( img => img.style.display = 'none' );
    imgArr[counter].style.display = 'block';
    counter++;
    if(counter == imgArr.length - 1) counter = 0;
}

setInterval(() => roll(), 500);
```

## EDIT (asked)

> How would i stop function roll if screen is greater then 1200 ?

so in that case you should use the `setInterval()` function :

```
function roll() {
    imgArr.map( img => img.style.display = 'none' );
    imgArr[counter].style.display = 'block';
    counter++;
    if(counter == imgArr.length - 1) counter = 0;
}

let interv = setInterval(() => roll(), 500);

window.onresize = () => {
    let windowWidth = window.innerWidth||d.documentElement.clientWidth||d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
    clearInterval(interv);
    if(windowWidth < 1200) {
        interv = setInterval(() => roll(), 500);
    } else {
        clearInterval(interv);
    }
}
```

Comment: it only breaks on resize can you help? So that I can accept thanks, man.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle that show that 'break on resize' ?

Comment: Yes sure here: https://codepen.io/Merdzanovich/pen/abbvPGv

On resize it breaks is there a solution to fix this? thanks!!!!

Comment: this problem doesn't depend on window resizing, maybe you have a screen big enough to resize down just a little bit and see nothing's wrong, but when you skrink it you have what you called a 'break' --> It's due to a CSS `@media (min-width or max-width`, you have a lot of it... a lot

Comment: The only problem is when i resize back to 1200 screen width. The display none and block will keep looping i want to stop that. How would i stop function roll if screen is greater then 1200.

Comment: I just re-edit it , now it works ! :)  you can check this behavior on this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/w0d6yg3h/